# Hosted tiled mapping (Portal) VS. Cached map service (Server)

Tags: tilecache, vector-tiles, arcgis-portal

I'm trying to create a detailed building basemap for the state of Washington in the Portal for ArcGIS on premises. In order to make the basemap moving faster, and considering it's large size and static, I simply chose to use **tiled mapping service** or **cached map service**. However, there are some concepts I am not very clear, especially about the difference between those two services.
Both services have a function to meet my requirement from Esri's documentation:

Hosted tiled service:

> Tile layers published to and hosted on your portal support fast visualization of large datasets using a collection of predrawn map images or tiles. Hosted tiles provide geographic context for your operational layers. For example, you might include tiles of streets in your neighborhood to provide a visual reference for the street signs in your feature layer. (http://server.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/publish-tiles.htm)

Cached map service:

> The best way to create fast map services is to cache them. When you cache a map service, the server draws the map at a set of scale levels that you define and saves the images. When the server receives a request for a map, it's much quicker to return one of these cached images than to draw the map again. (http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/windows/tutorial-creating-a-cached-map-service.htm)

Here are five (5) questions:

1. What's the difference between those two methods? It seems both of
   them can manage the caching properties in the Service Editor; while 
   the hosted tiled mapping is published thru the Portal, while the
   cached map service thru the server. Some people say they are the
   same (https://geonet.esri.com/thread/79128).
2. Moreover, publishing thru the Portal only has two options for the
   Capabilities: Tiled Mapping and Feature Access; while there are more
   capabilities choices by publishing thru the Server. Does that mean
   publishing thru the Portal is less functional than publishing thru
   the Server?
3. And why there are both "Tield Mapping" choice and "Caching" for
   publishing thru the Portal; while only one choice, *Caching*, is
   availabe for publishing thru Server? Are they the same?
4. Does the **federation** affect these two methods, publishing thru
   Portal or Server?

Service Editor when publishing a hosted tiled mapping (Portal):
[image]

Service Editor when publishing to a Server:
[image]

5. After publishing the tiled/cached service, there is an option to *View Cache Status* in "My Hosted Services"; while there is no such option in "GIS Servers" in the Catalog. How to understand this "inconsistence"?

My Hosted Services (Portal for ArcGIS):

[image]

GIS Servers/Hosted folder:

[image]

Here are answers I got from Esri support, and you can reopen this post if it will be helpful for other GISers.

1. One is hosted, the other is published to server. Essentially the same, depending on how you want to consume them.
2. No. Server has more capabilities because Portal does not support certain capabilities for hosted services (i.e. KML, WMS, WFS, etc).
3. Portal is preconfigured with basemaps (like AGOL). 
   Usually use feature services to work with Portal (add FS to web map)
   Tiled mapping would be to include a custom basemap
   Server can have a map service enabled without caching (dynamic) – uses DataStore.
   Portal will host it on Server.
4. It can. All existing map services will appear on Portal and you can use those map services dynamically.
5. Cached map is only being hosted on Server. Server will not manage items published to Portal. Only serves as a reference for the service, not as a manager. Portal overrides most Server functionality.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Five questions is too many for the GIS  SE "Focused question/Best Answer" model.  Each one looks like an independent question to me.  Together they're nearly a consulting contract (thought I imagine you could get someone from Esri to discuss it with you for a few hours for free).

Comment: I edited the post with answers I got from Esri support, and you can reopen this post if it will be helpful for other GISers.

Comment: Thanks for including those answers! Very useful.  If you have time, can I suggest you cut and paste these into a new answer, and then mark your own answer as the resolution.

Comment: I'd love to. However, it seems there is no "Answer Your Question" button for this post ~